# Finding row index of a row from a selected number of row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Here is my mysql query

```
SELECT network_mst.NetworkId,network_mst.NetworkName,network_mst.InternationalDBStatus,network_mst.Of fshoreDBStatus,network_mst.InterDBStatus,network_mst.IntraDBStatus 
FROM network_mst INNER JOIN carrier_network ON network_mst.NetworkId=carrier_network.NetworkId
INNER JOIN user_network ON network_mst.NetworkId=user_network.NetworkId WHERE UserId=1
AND carrier_network.CarrierId IN (1) GROUP BY network_mst.NetworkId ORDER BY  network_mst.NetworkName;
```

The resulting data is 
[image]

Sorry for the small image.It has a field called NetworkId.
So my question is how to find the row index of a row with NetworkId 2.Here the answer is row index of row with NetworkId 2 is 3.
But how to find this using query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @rownum = 0; 
Select *
FROM
(
   Select *,  (@rownum := @rownum+1) as rank
   FROM
   (
      -- Your current query here
   ) t
) sub WHERE rank = 3
```

This query should return the row with the `netword_id = 2` since it is the third row. But you have to watch out the `ORDER BY` clause in the inner most query since it is what controls the order of the ranking.